# 3rd monitor with Dell Precision 490

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, dell-precision

I am trying to go for a 3 monitor setup on my workstation, but need some information before I can invest in a new graphics card and 2 monitors. Would be glad to get some help here:

I have a Dell Precision 490 workstation with Nvidia Quadro FX 4500 graphics card (PCI-E 16) on it. It has 2 DVI-D ports that can support 2 monitors upto 2560x1600 resolution.

For the third monitor, I was looking at Nvidia NVS 295 card, however I am not sure if it is physically possible to hook another card to the motherboard.

Here is the spec of Precision 490:
http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/precn/en/spec_precn_490_en.pdf

Can I attach NVS 295 to it? If not, what options do I have?

Comment: If this is not the right StackExchange site to ask this question, please tell me which one is.

Comment: Your post will be automatically transfered :)

Answer (score 3):

According to [this website](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003HFTN1M) (Dell's specs didn't list the necessary information), your motherboard only has one PCI Express x16 slot, so you can't install that particular graphics card into your current machine.

You could purchase a new motherboard with multiple PCI Express x16 slots, purchase a graphics card that supports 3 or more independent displays (there are several on the market that support up to four) to replace your current graphics card, or purchase a PCI Express x1 graphics card to use as an additional card.

Answer (score 0):

Matrox sells a really great expansion for your computer allowing you to connect more monitors (even more than just the extra one, depending on the product!). Here's a list of the expansions available on their site http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/.

Unlike most devices of this variety, which can't handle much more than maybe a VLC Media Player window, the devices that Matrox offer function much like that from adding an extra GPU to your PC- they use your installed GPU to process the output for the extra monitors that you would like to install. With a Quadro FX 4500 you should be able to add a good 3 monitors *in addition* to the ones already on your internal GPU! **This means 5 monitors in total!**

I'm sure that this would be useful to improving your productivity! :D